# jQuery plugins functions overwrite

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins, overwrite

I have implemented several jQuery plugins for my current project.

Since some plugins have functions with the same name, the one called in the last one defined.

Here is the definition of my first plugin:

```
$(function($)
{
    $.fn.initPlugin1 = function(parameters)
    {
        var defaultParameters = {};
        $(this).data('parameters', $.extend(defaultParameters, parameters));
        return $(this);
    };

    $.fn.function1 = function(){ console.log('Function 1.'); };

    $.fn.callFunction = function(){ $(this).function1(); };
});
```

And here is the definition of my second plugin:

```
$(function($)
{
    $.fn.initPlugin2 = function(parameters)
    {
        var defaultParameters = {};
        $(this).data('parameters', $.extend(defaultParameters, parameters));
        return $(this);
    };

    $.fn.function2 = function(){ console.log('Function 2.'); };

    $.fn.callFunction = function(){ $(this).function2(); };
});
```

I have also this scenario :

```
$("#div1").initPlugin1().callFunction();
$("#div2").initPlugin2().callFunction();
```

For this specific scenario the consoles shows: `Function 2. Function 2.`

In fact, since the `callFunction()` is also defined in the second plugin, this is the one used.

I would like some advise on what is the best way to solve this problem.
Is it possible to create a thing similiar to a namespace ?

Comment: `$.fn.callFunction` is the jquery plugin, why would you extext it to be different in two cases. So just don't use prototype method for this.

Comment: Do you want to be able to write like this also: `$("#div1").callFunction();` ?

Comment: @dfsq It would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```js
$(function($) {
  $.fn.initPlugin1 = function() {
    console.log('Initialized Plugin1');
    return $(this);
  };


});
$(function($) {
  $.fn.initPlugin2 = function() {
    console.log('Initialized Plugin2');
    return $(this);
  };

  $.fn.callFunction = function(param) {
    $(this).append(param);
  };
});
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(
    function() {
      $("#div1").initPlugin1(); //Run correctly
      $("#div2").initPlugin2(); //Run correctly

      $("#div1").initPlugin1().callFunction('function1');
      $("#div2").initPlugin2().callFunction('function2');
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This way `initPlugin1` is not called.

Comment: Did the job ! Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @syms I was refactoring my code with your method when I got a strange error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of null`.

Apparently, the `this` object is not the same as before.

I was using this plugin structure:

 $(function($) {
  $.fn.initPlugin1 = function() {
   return $(this);
  };

  $.fn.initPlugin1.function1 = function() {
   $(this).append('Function 1.');
  };

  $.fn.initPlugin1.callFunction = function() {
   $(this).initPlugin1.function1();
  };
 });

Comment: @syms I have created a new example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Syms Sure It will work but that's not what I want to do. Each plugin should have its own `testFunction` since the content of this one differs from a plugin to an other.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @syms answer, I have created the following example.

**Plugin1:**

```
$(function($) {
    $.fn.initPlugin1 = function() {
        console.log('Initialized Plugin1');
        return $(this);
    };

    $.fn.initPlugin1.testFunction = function() {
        $(this).append('Function 1.');
    };
});
```

**Plugin2:**

```
$(function($) {
    $.fn.initPlugin2 = function() {
        console.log('Initialized Plugin2');
        return $(this);
    };

    $.fn.initPlugin2.testFunction = function() {
        $(this).append('Function 2.');
    };
});
```

**Main:**

```
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $("#div1").initPlugin1(); //Run correctly
            $("#div2").initPlugin2(); //Run correctly

            $("#div1").initPlugin1.testFunction(); //Fail
            $("#div2").initPlugin2.testFunction(); //Fail
        });

})(jQuery);
```

When I run my code, I got the following error: `Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of null`.

Apparently, the `this` object is corrupted.